# How to build XML device description for a minimalistic but fully DLNA compatible audio renderer device?

Tags: audio, upnp, dlna, gupnp

I'm developing an embedded DLNA audio media renderer in C++ which will capture audio stream and use it as a source for LED controller to create visual effects.

Currently I have chosen gupnp library. Its documentation claims that it can generate C code "scaffold" if I feed it with a correct service description XML file.
I read DLNA specifications documentation but it's not easy to put all the absolute minimal requirements together. For now, I know only that I'll need ConnectionManager, RenderingControl and maybe AVTransport service but I'm not sure which methods will be absolutely required to allow the device to receive mp3/aac/wav audio streams from any DLNA media server/radio streamer etc. out there.

I'll be grateful for information where to find such a template or instructions for building a DLNA compatible XML audio renderer template (MediaRenderer:1 should work fine) with minimum required functions and variables to feed into UPNP generator tools (specifically, gupnp).

Comment: I sympathize with the problem of getting started but building a renderer that works with a specific control point and mediaserver is already too large an issue for a SO question. Building a _DLNA compatible_ renderer means covering a million little details... There's a reason the DLNA docs are 800 pages or so (on top of the UPnP-AV specs that actually define the services).

Comment: Yes, the documents describe all possible media formats - audio, video, images, and UPNP includes also home automation etc. and there are also lots of large (too large for my embedded needs) open source projects for DLNA streaming. Out of this all I somehow need to extract the bare minimum for rendering mp3/aac audio. Currently I have only HTC phone as a DLNA signal source and I'll try at least to get it working.